# slack bot error: 'user_is_bot' for channels.join

Tags: slack-api, botkit

I am trying to create a new channel using slack api https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.join but getting this response

```
info: ** API CALL: https://slack.com/api/channels.join
Response :  { ok: false, error: 'user_is_bot' }
```

I tried this

```
controller.hears('hello', ['direct_message', 'direct_mention', 'mention'], function (bot, message) {
  bot.api.channels.join({'name':'nag'}, function (err, response) {
    console.log("Response : ",response);
  })
});
```

If I am mistaken please let me know. I have started learning slack api.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you are getting `user_is_bot` is that [channels.join](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.join) can not be used by a bot user. As it says in the documentation for this method:

> `user_is_bot`: This method cannot be called by a bot user.

To create channel you will want to use [channels.create](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.create). However, that method can also not be used by a bot user.

The common solution is to use the full `access_token`, not the `bot_access_token` that your Slack app received from Slack after installing it with OAuth for all methods that bot users can not use, e.g. creating a new channel.

Here is the example from the [OAuth documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) on how the response from Slack with both tokens look like:

> ```
> {
>     "access_token": "xoxp-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXX",
>     "scope": "incoming-webhook,commands,bot",
>     "team_name": "Team Installing Your Hook",
>     "team_id": "XXXXXXXXXX",
>     "incoming_webhook": {
>         "url": "https://hooks.slack.com/TXXXXX/BXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX",
>         "channel": "#channel-it-will-post-to",
>         "configuration_url": "https://teamname.slack.com/services/BXXXXX"
>     },
>     "bot":{
>         "bot_user_id":"UTTTTTTTTTTR",
>         "bot_access_token":"xoxb-XXXXXXXXXXXX-TTTTTTTTTTTTTT"
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: In the mean time this has changed and bots are supposed to be able to join channels autonomously, but for some weird reason I can't get it to work.